# Android get a res folder to show under resource type

Tags: android, xml

I created a folder under res/xml. When I create a new xml file, xml does not show under resource type like the other resources under res. How can I make it appear?

Edit: I am using eclipse

Comment: Just curious did you try to refresh the project?

Comment: I just refreshed it, it didn't do anything.

Comment: Right now I am just creating the xml file into other folder and dragging it into res/xml. I know this can't be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the Dialog in eclipse with the Resource Type dropdown then know it's a static predefined dropdown. It won't have all possibilities or any special setup you are trying to achieve. You can simply create an xml file in the folder without having to drag it there.

Answer (score 1):

Try create your xml inside layout folder and use `R.layout.YourLayoutName` and it should appear successfully